# My boss is trying to throw me under the bus, for his own mistake

Tags: work-environment, ethics, teamwork

There was this big project from a huge client that my company got. We are a team of 12 people. That includes 3 developers, 1 team lead and my manager

We got assigned work based on Sprints. There is this thing called account allocation, which defines the budget, cost of resources (Jira, Office software, etc.), to be done by the client. Let's call it **Step 1**. One of the key component of the account allocation is issuing **Account id** for Microsoft Azure (Cloud).

It so happened that I was responsible for Step 2 of the project. However, the account allocation and its finalization took 3 weeks, due to some complications. So, even though I had nothing to do with Step 1, I was already behind schedule. When Step 1 completed, I was already ready with Step 2 , having completed all the necessary codes to be deployed. However, it got unsuccessful. Up until then, I was in good terms with the client, who would appreciate my efforts and my knowledge in explaining stuff to him. But, after the delay , the client was a bit hasty.

I was stuck with my task for 3 days , and not even my manager helped me. No one from my team helped me. Looking at the error code, I was quite certain that there is some error in Step 1, and that needs to be fixed and that we need help from accounts team, which can be obtained by informing the client. However, my manager kept insisting that we should **not** inform the client and there must be some issue with the code base.

Now, here is what was sketchy from the beginning :-

1. The manager had agreed to deliver the project in less time than actually required. So the timeline was already rigid.
2. Due to strict timeline, the manager did not allow me to go through documents of the boiler plate code that we were supposed to use. The boiler plate code was available from client's side, but was done by other team members, under the same manager as mine. So, without approval from manager , I could not access the documents.
3. The manager handed over the code, done by other team, for similar project, for the same client (again this team was under the same manager as mine). I only had to modify some of the stuff that our project needed. Even though I insisted that I go through the code, manager kept saying that I don't have time to do that.
4. There are 2 people in my team who live in the same city as the manager, so I think that he plays favoritism.

I was on leave for 1 day, and when I got back, I came to know that the issue was fixed, with some other test case, and that I need to deploy my code. The 2 team members, (who live in same city as manager), found out the error, with the help of team members of other project of the same client, and told me to make changes according.

However, my issue still persisted. After 3 days, when I went through what changes those 2 members did, I found out that the fix that those two team members told me had nothing to do with the actual error, rather, unknowingly, they had used a different MS Azure Account Id. Immediately, I told them to test their code with our Azure id and it failed.

So, when I went to the manager to talk about it, he rather scolded me saying that this account id thing should be known to me (even when he didnt entertain my request earlier). Moreover, he let one of the team members (living in his city) take the credit for the step of figuring out the problem, and the success as well.

Also, the client still does not know that the problem is with account Id (that the deployment was done in a different Azure account) and the manager is still insisting that we do not inform the client. This is very scary for me.

I am not sure, if it is important regarding the account Id, but if it is a big issue, the manager is definitely going to put the blame on me.

In addition, I am way too scared of this manager of mine, now that I saw his true colours.

I am documenting everything right from the start of the project to whatever I had asked to my manager, and was denied. What should I do if the situation is escalated ? Am I in trouble for being sidelined from the project, and hence losing my job ?

Comment: I am afraid we do not have an answer to your question. Whether what happend was malice or incompetence is impossible to say for us. You always have the option to look for a better job, regardless of your current standing or suspicions in your job right now.

Comment: I think you are worried too much. Yes, there is some issue, and you will have to fix it, and calm your boss down. But, you won't lose your job over it unless this happens every week for the next 9 months.

Comment: To me this sounds like a lack of thrust and a mislead understanding  of "agile". However, you communication seems to be a part of the problem, your post comes of as very defensive.

Answer (score 3):

So there are 2 questions here - one is the technical question which smells awfully like a permissions issue inside of Azure or a specific account is not authorized for code deployment.

The second question however is the business/management question:

- Without knowing your geographic location, it's unknown if your job is at risk.

For example, in the US, in an At-Will state - you can be dismissed for wearing the wrong colour tie. Assuming you aren't in an At-Will state - it would be a dubious action to fire you. If this is the first instance of an issue, then worst case would be to go on a PIP.

That said - there are a number of statements in your question that do not add up/make sense. For example - you say the Account creation was delayed, so you couldn't do anything - but then you say that due to timeframes you didn't have time to review the Templated code that you were going to be using?

Reading between the lines though - it sounds like your Manager over-promised and is out of their depth. If everything is as you say, then it may be that they are looking for a scapegoat.

Firstly **Whatever you do - don't have a mudslinging contest in front of the customer**

Next up - Who else is in your leadership chain apart from your Manager? Do you have an HR department?

What you will want to do here is to raise the issue of the aspects of the project you are having trouble with. Don't assign blame - just stick to the facts:

"This step is at risk because of X, Y and Z"

For example "We have issues with the deployment account, which is still not fully resolved" and "Some of the required resources are not as readily available as needed for a project of this type"

Again - not pointing fingers at people, just laying out what is happening and why you are raising it. Make sure you have the receipts - Emails where issues were raised, confirmations where it didn't work, replies where you didn't get access.

Let the evidence of the situation lead the person who is reviewing to a conclusion.